# MacBook Pro Shift key problem

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware

My MacBook Pro with Retina display has the following problem:

1. Left Shift Key not functioning
2. Sometimes Shift is on automatically and when restarting, will restart in safe mode

What I've done:

1. Try using USB keyboard, the problem persist (always in Shift e.g press <kbd>8</kbd> will output *)
2. Restart holding <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, get option to reinstall and three others
3. Restart holding <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>O</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, the problem is gone but not for long (first time, it takes a day to happen again.. now, every 30 minutes or so)
4. Install Karabiner-EventViewer, the press the Left Key definitely give no response; when my MacBook Pro in Shift, the log shows Shift flags for every key pressed.
5. Reinstall macOS, seems not solving my problem

How can I stay out of safe mode, and use the functionality of shift keys?

Comment: You need to replace your keyboard.  See this [question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298853/keyboard-key-stuck-or-not-being-recognized-how-to-fix/298854#298854) for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with MacBook Pro A1502 EMC 2875 on macOS 10.12.6 fresh installed and previous 10.10.

I also see graphics glitch on PWD logon switching to the desktop, and it's sluggish.

I re-seated ribbon cable and reset SMC. It worked for a while, then it returned.

I believe the keyboard got light liquid damage, so I'm changing it as a test.

Comment: Please do let me know if changing keyboard solve the problem. The graphics glitch because it is in safe mode, imho.

Comment: yes it sometimes did it without safemode.

i unplugged battery and cleaned it with %100 alcohol and working good so far.